# Alignment of bootstrap input spinner is not working

Tags: css

I am going to use **bootstrap input spinner** for my cart web page some old version bootsrap.min.css clashing to align the content correctly ,Can any one help me how to fix it

my code

```
[<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>bootstrap-input-spinner</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <style type="text/css">
        h2 {
            margin-top: 2rem;
        }

        h3 {
            margin-top: 1rem;
        }

        /*noinspection CssUnusedSymbol*/
        .input-group,
        input.test-value-input {
            max-width: 250px;
        }

        .code {
            background-color: #f1f2f3;
            font-family: Courier, monospace;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <section class="container pt-3">
        <h3>Simple Integer</h3>
        <p>
            <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" />
        </p>
    </section>
    <!-- bootstrap needs jQuery -->
    <script src="./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="src/bootstrap-input-spinner.js"></script>
    <script>
        $("input\[type='number'\]").inputSpinner()
    </script>
</body>

</html>][1]
```

i want output like this[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTdkZ.png)

but am getting this design [wrongdesing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNEHP.png)

Comment: Which bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: hi @PasinduMadhuranga,old they used v3.2.0 ,But now i want use Bootstrap v4.3.1 version. If am going to applied *Bootstrap v4.3.1* version  some old design will not working correctly

Comment: Have you tried doing `display: inline-block;` or `display: inline-flex;`?

Comment: @shivu, Some of the components class names are changed since v4, looking at their documentation might help. https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3

Comment: I tried like this `<section class="container pt-3">
        <div style="display: inline-flex;">
            <p>
                <input type="number" value="1" min="1" max="10" />
            </p>
        </div>
    </section>`

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the question, but by judging at the image you inserted, I think you are looking for this: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/input-group/#button-addons